# How to restrict WiFi change on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm, apple-configurator

I have this solution for my customer's retail stores - they have iPad Air 2, with iOS 8.1.3, router and workstation with large TV and it's absolutely necessary that the iPad will stay connected only to WiFi I am providing with those routers. If anyone changes to another hotspot, the solution won't work. So I am looking for some ways that will prevent that, either in settings or via some app..
Also, it might work with apple configurator, but I couldn't find any site where it is mentioned.

Thx for advices

Comment: If you have an app and the users are not supposed to leave the app you can activate "guided access". this makes it impossible to leave the active app (without entering a passcode).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no means to restrict iOS devices to a single WiFi, even with an MDM and device supervision. I have a close relationship with Apple and this has been ask from education and retail partners for over 4 years now. I feel your pain.

A "workaround" for this would be possible if you happen to be using a single app that you have developed to access these resources. If that is the case you can either interrogate which SSID the device is attached to and throw a warning if it is not correct. There are also a myriad of other examples like this to **detect** the wrong SSID or spoofed SSID but no way to currently lock the device to the correct SSID.